# Find all $n$ such that if $\gcd(a,n)=1$ then $a^2=1$ mod $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, cryptography

I really have no idea where to start with this question:

Find all $n$ such that if $gcd(a,n)=1$ then $a^2=1$ mod $n$

I found out that it works for $n = 8$, since all odd numbers modulo 8 have order $\leq 2$.

It looks so easy... Can somebody help me? Thanks!

Update: Immediately after posting this, something reminded me of the Carmichael function. Maybe I need to use that one?

Comment: Lemma: 1 mod n = n - 1, then a^2 = n - 1. If GCD(a,n) = 1 then they are relatively prime. Can we also imagine that GCD(a^2, n) = 1 will also hold? Then GCD(n-1,n) must equal 1 for all n. The you can then use eulers equation to finding GCD's to find a n's that are satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Note that $n=24$ works, and therefore so do all divisors of $24$. Why $24$? Because $3$ and $8$ work, and are relatively prime.

To prove there are no more, first suppose that some prime $\ge 5$ divides $n$. Show that $n$ does not have the required property.

Next suppose that $2^4$ divides $n$. Show that $n$ does not have the required property.

Finally, show that if $9$ divides $n$, then $n$ does not have the required property.

**Added:** We give a sample proof, doing the middle one. Let $n=2^k m$, where $k\ge 4$ and $m$ is odd. Let $a$ be a solution of the system of congruences $x\equiv 3\pmod{2^k}$, $x\equiv 1\pmod{m}$. There is a solution, by the Chinese Remainder Theorem, and it is relatively prime to $n$.  Since $a^2\not\equiv 1\pmod{2^k}$, we have $a^2\not\equiv 1\pmod{n}$.

Answer (score 0):

All we need is [Carmichael Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CarmichaelFunction.html) $\displaystyle \lambda(n)|2$

If the highest power of prime $p>2$ that divides $n$ in $k, \phi(p^k)=p^{k-1}$ will divide $\displaystyle \lambda(n)$

$\displaystyle\implies p\le3,k\le1$

If $p=2,\lambda(2^k)=2^{k-2}$ which must divide $\displaystyle \lambda(n)\implies k-2\le1$